# How to convert Vanilla JS to NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and NextJS, I have a small project that uses Hotel Datepicker Master with Fecha date formatting and parsing, which is installed on my project. I'm trying to convert my project to React/NextJS but the problem is I can't figure out how to convert my Vanilla JS code to NextJS.

Here is my Vanilla JS code:

```
(function() {
let today = new Date();
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
let input1 = document.querySelector('#checkIn');
input1.value = fecha.format(today, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + 
fecha.format(tomorrow, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  let demo1 = new HotelDatepicker(input1);
})();
```

Result:
[image]

And here is what I tried so far on NextJS:

*_app.js file*

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../hotel-datepicker-master/dist/css/hotel-datepicker.css'
import '../node_modules/fecha/dist/fecha.min.js'
import '../hotel-datepicker-master/dist/js/hotel-datepicker.js'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

*hero.jsx file*

```
useEffect(() => {
let today = new Date();
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
let input1 = dateInput.current.value;
input1.value = fecha.format(today, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + 
fecha.format(tomorrow, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
let demo1 = new HotelDatepicker(input1);}, [dateInput]);
```

Result: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')*

Can you please give me an idea of how to do the conversion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `fecha` is not defined in your code. So it is getting an undefined error

Comment: @AhammedKM, it is defined on the _app.js file. I have updated my question.

Comment: You can use Script tag from next/script for importing external .js files. `<Script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/fecha/dist/fecha.min.js" />`. Also you can try `import` as well.

Comment: I tried this import '../node_modules/fecha/dist/fecha.min.js' import '../hotel-datepicker-master/dist/js/hotel-datepicker.js' in the _document.js file, hero.jsx and _app.js, to try to make it work. Also, I tried using next/script but I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: HotelDatepicker is not a constructor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import { format } from 'fecha';
```

And then

```
input1.value = format(today, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' +
```

Comment: Емил Цоков thank you so much, date is now displaying in the input field, but the problem now is I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: HotelDatepicker is not a constructor" I tried this import '../node_modules/fecha/dist/fecha.min.js'
import '../hotel-datepicker-master/dist/js/hotel-datepicker.js' in the _document.js file, hero.jsx and _app.js, to try to make it work. Also, I tried using next/script but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use react date range picker instead of hotel date picker master with fecha, it is easy to implement on nextjs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: answer is a comment